# How to sort an array list according to different criteria?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Hi everyone (if my english is bad sorry),
I have to code an Android Application at school.
The project concerns a music player, i got an arraylist of musics, and i want to be able to sort them by differents criteria (Artist, Title and Album). I already done some code but it only work for the titles. I let you my code below, i want to modify typeTri according to the button pressed, i got a clicklistener on each button (Artist,Title and Album). Thank you for your help

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Musique a){
        String typeTri = "Artistes";
        if (typeTri.equals("Artistes")){

            if (a.getArtiste().compareTo(this.getArtiste())>0)
                return -1;
            if (a.getArtiste().compareTo(this.getArtiste())<0)
                return 1;
            if (a.getArtiste().equals(this.getArtiste()))
                return 0;
        }

        if (typeTri.equals("Albums")){

            if (a.getAlbum().compareTo(this.getAlbum())>0)
                return -1;
            if (a.getAlbum().compareTo(this.getAlbum())<0)
                return 1;
            if (a.getAlbum().equals(this.getAlbum()))
                return 0;
        }

        if (typeTri.equals("Titres")){

            if (a.getTitre().compareTo(this.getTitre())>0)
                return -1;
            if (a.getTitre().compareTo(this.getTitre())<0)
                return 1;
            if (a.getTitre().equals(this.getTitre()))
                return 0;
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You can just call e.g. `return a.getArtiste().compareTo(this.getArtiste());`; there is no need for the three cases. If you want reverse order, simply swap `a` and `this`.

Comment: Yes but i want to be able to sort by artist, by album and by title according to the button pressed on screen.
Here i sort by Artist in any case and i want to know how to modify typeTri according to the button pressed

Comment: In that case, you need to remove the `equals` case, because provided your `compareTo` is implemented consistently (and for `String` it is) if it's not greater or less, it is equal. As such, it will always return from one of the conditional branches. Plus, you can never compare by more than one attribute without `typeTri` changing its value mid-execution.

Comment: Ok so i think using compareTo isn't a solution. Do you know how to make it possible with another method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks in your code like you are making `Musique` implement `Comparable<Musique>`. Referring to the Javadoc of that class:

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's natural ordering...

If you want to sort things by different criteria depending upon the context, then you are not sorting them by a natural order. As such, it is not appropriate to use `Comparable` in this case, but rather to define external `Comparator`s.

It would be easiest to have several instances of `Comparator<Musique>`, one for each of your current `typeTri` values:

```
enum MusiqueComparator implements Comparator<Musique> {
  ARTISTE {
    @Override public int compare(Musique a, Musique b) {
      return b.getArtiste().compareTo(a.getArtiste());
    }
  },
  ALBUM {
    @Override public int compare(Musique a, Musique b) {
      return b.getAlbum().compareTo(a.getAlbum());
    }
  },
  TITRE {
    @Override public int compare(Musique a, Musique b) {
      return b.getTitre().compareTo(a.getTitre());
    }
  }
}
```

Now, when you click the button to sort by, e.g. Artist, pass `MusiqueComparator.ARTISTE` to [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) to sort your list by that criterion.

Comment: It tells me that sort in collections cannot be applied to MusiqueComparator

Comment: What is the list you are passing in as the first parameter? Is it a `List<Musique>`?

Comment: The list i'm passing to ? Collections.sort?

Comment: Yes. You have to call `Collections.sort` with a `List` **and** optionally a type-compatible `Comparator`.

Comment: My Array list is called ListeMusique and here is my onclicklistener

private OnClickListener bAlbumsListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Collections.sort(MusiqueComparator.ALBUM);
            ListeMusiqueView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }
    };

Comment: Right, so you're not passing the list to `Collections.sort` - how do you think it can sort a list if you don't give it the list?

Comment: I found the solution sorry .. that was obvious

Comment: My comment above describes it: "You have to call `Collections.sort` with a `List` **and** optionally a type-compatible `Comparator`."

Comment: It works, i thank you a lot for your fast help Andy i will continue to study your tips to really understand how it works!

Answer (score 1):

In your onClickListener try this

```
if(musiqueList!=null) {
            Collections.sort(musiqueList, new Comparator<Musique>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Musique item1, Musique item2) {
                    if(typeTri.equals("Titres"){
                        //compare your items by Titres
                     } else if(typeTri.equals("Albums")
                        //compare your items by Albums
                     else //compare your items by Artistes
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily sort any Collection (List<> is a Collection) using the following function:

```
Collections.sort(arrayListToSort, new MyComparator());
```

You will need to provide your own logic for comparing llike this:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<YourType>
```

{

```
@Override
 public int compare(YourType lhs, YourType rhs)
 {
    //your logic for comparing these two, you need to return int, 0 if they're equal, negative value if lhs is greater, positive if it's smaller
 }
```

}